# How to define runtime constants in a DLL and use them in another DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2017, linker-errors

I created this example as 3 Visual Studio projects: a DLL library named `'Constants'` that contains runtime constants (`IDs`), another DLL library named `'Functions'` that uses the constants from the first library, and a console EXE that prints out constants by calling functions from the `'Functions'` library.

[image]

#### Constants/src/Constants.h:

```
#pragma once

__declspec(dllexport) extern const int ID1;
__declspec(dllexport) extern const int ID2;

namespace {

    int nextID();

}
```

#### Constants/src/Constants.cpp:

```
#include "Constants.h"

const int ID1 = nextID();
const int ID2 = nextID();

namespace {
    int nextID() {
        static int ID = 0;
        return ID++;
    }
}
```

#### Functions/src/Functions.h:

```
#pragma once

__declspec(dllexport) int getID1();
__declspec(dllexport) int getID2();
```

#### Functions/src/Functions.cpp:

```
#include "Functions.h"
#include "Constants.h"

int getID1() {
    return ID1;
}

int getID2() {
    return ID2;
}
```

#### Console/src/Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Functions.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Library Constants: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << getID1() << std::endl;
    std::cout << getID2() << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

If I link `'Constants'` library directly to the EXE and print constants directly, then everything works fine, but if I link `'Constants'` to the `'Functions'` and then `'Functions'` to the EXE (print using `getID` functions) then I get this error:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Constants, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Constants.cpp
1>   Creating library C:\dev\DLLTest\bin\Win32\Debug\constants.lib and object C:\dev\DLLTest\bin\Win32\Debug\constants.exp
1>Constants.vcxproj -> C:\dev\DLLTest\bin\Win32\Debug\constants.dll
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Functions, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>Functions.cpp
2>   Creating library C:\dev\DLLTest\bin\Win32\Debug\functions.lib and object C:\dev\DLLTest\bin\Win32\Debug\functions.exp
2>Functions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const ID1" (?ID1@@3HB)
2>Functions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const ID2" (?ID2@@3HB)
2>C:\dev\DLLTest\bin\Win32\Debug\functions.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
2>Done building project "Functions.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Console, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>Main.cpp
3>Console.vcxproj -> C:\dev\DLLTest\bin\Win32\Debug\console.exe
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I don't understand why linking from DLL to DLL in this case fails.

Comment: It needs to be dllexport in the DLL that defines it, but dllimport in any code that uses it.

Comment: this all looks plain wrong.What do you mean by "link"?if you have two independent modules running you cant `extern` smth from one to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Constants.h` should be:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef CONSTANTS_DLLEXPORT
#define CONSTANTS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CONSTANTS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

CONSTANTS_API extern const int ID1;
CONSTANTS_API extern const int ID2;

namespace {

    int nextID();

}
```

`Functions.h` should be:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef FUNCTIONS_DLLEXPORT
#define FUNCTIONS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FUNCTIONS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

FUNCTIONS_API int getID1();
FUNCTIONS_API int getID2();
```

And then `FUNCTIONS_DLLEXPORT` needs to be added to the 'Preprocessor Definitions' of `'Functions'` project, and `CONSTANTS_DLLEXPORT` to the 'Preprocessor Definitions' of the `'Constants'` project.

Comment: @Ruks I made this a full answer, and reverted question back to the original question.

Comment: I would avoid the name DECLSPEC here. The word `declspec` in all casing variants should be reserved for the operation of specifying a declaration. The result should describe the intention like FUNCTIONS_API, similar to WINAPI for Windows API functions.

Comment: @harper I changed my answer according to your suggestion.